# What does default gateway from ipconfig on Windows means?

Tags: windows, routing, ipconfig

What does `Default gateway` properties of every network adapter from `ipconfig /all` command's output means?

As far as I understand, default gateway is the next-hop IP that is assigned to address 0.0.0.0 in the routing table and can be seen by `route print` command.

How `Default gateway`s from network adapter's properties correspond to the one from routing table?

Is there an analogy of this `Default gateway` properties of network adapters on Linux?

Comment: Appropriate routes will be created for all default gateways, on both Windows and Linux. Are you asking how to match routes and network interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

> What does Default gateway properties of every network adapter from ipconfig /all command's output means?

You could say it's the configuration parameter from which a `::/0` or `0.0.0.0/0` route will be generated.

> As far as I understand, default gateway is the next-hop IP that is assigned to address 0.0.0.0 in the routing table and can be seen by route print command.

More specifically `0.0.0.0/0` (with netmask 0.0.0.0). The network mask or prefix length is also important – for example, a 0.0.0.0/1 route wouldn't be the "default gateway" because it only covers half the possible addresses. (This is not made-up – OpenVPN frequently creates 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1 routes instead of changing the default gateway.)

> Is there an analogy of this Default gateway properties of network adapters on Linux?

In various network configuration software – possibly. For example, the 'ifupdown' tools used by Debian (i.e. the `/etc/network/interfaces` file) have only a 'gateway' keyword for the default route.

At kernel level – no. The only way to create a default route is literally by creating a `::/0` or `0.0.0.0/0` route.

So you *might* have a "Default gateway" field in the GUI, but it always gets translated to 0.0.0.0/0 before being passed to the kernel's network stack.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, do I understand correctly that these `Default gateway` properties that are shown in `ipconfig`'s output do not have any impact on actual routing of packets, only records in routing table do?